# Facebook not returning all_mutual_friends anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented graph api call to get mutual friends between two users, it was working fine but suddenly stopped working. I have this api call

```
graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{facebook_id}?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends)&access_token={access_token}&appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof}
```

It returned the mutual friends in this call, but now the response is

```
{
    "context": {
        "id": "..."
    },
    "id": "..."
}
```

And if I try to make a second call using context id I get an empty array

```
graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{context_id}/mutual_friends?access_token={access_token}&appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof}

{
    "data": []
}
```

Both users have users_permissions accepted. Mutual friends api is pending to review but it should work between developer users, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutual friends can only return users who authorized your App. That includes the list of mutual friends too, not just the two users in question. Which makes the Mutual Friends API pretty pointless, i guess. That is why they removed it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#friends-4-4

> The Mutual Friends API is no longer available.

Comment: As it's written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends): "All friends that the viewer and the target person have in common. This includes the friends who do not use your app"

Comment: docs may not be up to date yet ;) - i will include a link that will make it clear.

Comment: @luschn Do you have any idea if the Mutual Friends API will be replaced by anything new? Or is it possible to get the mutual friends and likes between two users from another endpoint?

Comment: i don´t think there will be another way. it would not make sense with the new data privacy thing.

Comment: The best that could be done is to use the user_friends permissions and do an intersection for those of the current user and those of the other party... and this would only be for mutual friends that are already on the platform

Comment: Is there documentation for this? @Jaime

Comment: what documentation? it´s the /me/friends endpoint, two times. and then you need to intersect the results.